# Finding missing record via PLSQL procedure

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a situation where i have a table in the local database, which always has to remain in sync with the database in the server. The records in the database of server is updated/deleted/inserted by third party and i have to keep the local DB in sync with the server.

My local machine receives current data in server. Suppose server DB has 4 records, my local machine receives those 4 records and i have to update my local DB with that using primary key.

When someone deletes a record in the server DB (only 3 records left), it only sends the remaining records (local DB receives only 3 records).

How can i find which record was deleted. (local machine receives primary keys to work with).

I tried following procedure, but it seems to be finding me the additional detail in the server, not the deleted.

```
PROCEDURE CheckDeletedRecord ( primarykeyRecieved IN varchar, toDeletedPrimarykey OUT varchar) AS
    vStorePrimaryKey VARCHAR2(45);
    BEGIN
      SELECT t.primarykeyOfTable INTO vStorePrimaryKey FROM tableName t where t.primarykeyOfTable = primarykeyRecieved 
      
      IF vStorePrimaryKey = '' THEN
        toDeletedPrimarykey := primarykeyRecieved ;
      END IF;  

    END CheckDeletedInfections;
```

Comment: A sql using exists / not exists will help.

Comment: exist / not exists works on two tables. I have only one table, other record is in cursor

Comment: You need to make the assignment to `toDeletedPrimaryKey` in  `EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND`

Comment: Why not just truncate the table and then insert all the new rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of `MERGE` and `DELETE`? You'd do *everything* in the same procedure, i.e. you don't have to "return" anything (as an `OUT` parameter). Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_check (pkrec in varchar2) is
begin
  -- if pkrec represents new or updated row
  merge into local_table a
    using server_table b
    on (a.pkrec = b.pkrec)
    when matched then update set (a.col1 = b.col1,
                                  a.col2 = b.col2, ...
                                 )
    when not matched then insert (pkrec, col1, col2, ...)
      values (pkrec, b.col1, b.col2, ...);

  -- remove rows which are deleted in the server table  
  delete from local_table a
    where not exists (select null 
                      from server_table b
                      where b.pkrec = a.pkrec
                     );
end;
```

Comment: This would work if i had two tables (local_table and server_table). But i only have one table i.e local_table. data fo server table is in cursor

Comment: How do data from "server" come to your "local" machine? In a file? If so, use it as an **external table** (so the above code would work). If not, how, then?

Comment: The data is directly saved in a database table in an encrypted way. then the encrypted data is decrypted using Views and then refcursors handles the rest.

Comment: What is that "database table", then? Yet another table in the local database, right? If so, you DO have two tables to work with - one is that "local table", and another one is "table in your local database which contains rows sent from the server table". If that's the case, why do you need yet another table in the local database? Why wouldn't you use view(s) that present decrypted data, based on table that contains data set from the server?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT INTO` throws `NO_DATA_FOUND` when the queried row doesn't exists, so(dummy is my test-table):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckDeletedRecord ( primarykeyRecieved IN varchar, toDeletedPrimarykey OUT varchar) AS

  vStorePrimaryKey varchar(45);

BEGIN
     SELECT t.primaryKey INTO vStorePrimaryKey FROM dummy t where t.primaryKey = primarykeyRecieved;
     
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            toDeletedPrimarykey :=  primarykeyRecieved ;

END CheckDeletedRecord; 
/
```

wrote a stored function to test it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION todelete (primarykeyRecieved IN varchar) return  varchar IS
l_retval  varchar(45) := ''; 
BEGIN
CheckDeletedRecord(primarykeyRecieved, l_retval);
return l_retval;
END;
/
```

Test Preparation:

```
insert into dummy values('EXISTS');
```

Tests:

```
select todelete('EXISTS') from dual;
```

OUTPUT

```
null
```

Not exists test

```
select todelete('EXISTS NOT') from dual;
```

OUTPUT

```
EXISTS NOT
```

and made it a

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3eb32f1b787136b497f80265ddaa7bab)